# Can conservation of momentum be violated?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, momentum, symmetry, conservation-laws, noethers-theorem

The law of the conservation of momentum has been established for hundred of years. Even in Quantum field theory every particle collision must be momentum-conserving if there is homogenity in space. Can this theorem still be violated?

If yes, what requirements must have a *momentum-non-conserving* theory? Is Heisenberg's uncertainity principle $\Delta x \Delta p \geq \frac{\hbar}{2}$ the possible answer? (*when one considers physical Systems in which $\Delta x$ is very small)*?

Comment: momentum isn't conserved globally in GR

Answer (score 24):

If the theory is invariant under translations in space, then linear momentum is conserved by [Noether's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem). If the theory is quantum, conservation holds only on the level of the expectation values (because that's the only meaningful level where you can talk about momentum as a *number* that's conserved in time), but it still holds.

There is no way out. You must break homogeneity/translation invariance to break momentum conservation. Heisenberg's uncertainty principle has nothing to do with it, as it is just a statement about standard deviations, not expectation values, and hence has no influence on the quantum version of conservation.

Comment: And how one can add inhomogenity of space in a theory without violating elementary consistence conditions?

Comment: You say that it's only meaningful to talk about expectation values, but isn't the whole probability spectrum conserved? Conservation of the spectrum would be a much stronger condition.

Comment: @kryomaxim: I did not claim that that is possible.

Comment: @kristjan: I didn't really say that it is the only meaningful level, it's the only meaningful level at which *momentum is a number*. The full quantum version of Noether's theorem are the Ward identities. I don't understand what you mean by "probability spectrum" or its conservation.

Comment: 1. We don't know what the nature is in galaxies far away from us; 2. Science is changing over the time; in times before Maxwell light was explained with the aether theory and 100 years ago no weak or strong force between subatomic particles were known, etc.; 3. What is with very curious phenomena like [this] (https://www.ecosia.org/search/images/q/ectoplasm+materialization)?; Hence, can we really regard momentum conservation as a ABSOLUTELY true fact???

Comment: In non-QFT, each state can be expressed as a superposition of energy eigenstates. The amplitudes of these eigenstates are constant, so the probability amplitudes of each of the possible measurement results are also conserved (this is what I call conservation of spectrum). I don't see why this shouldn't work in QFT (I don't know much about QFT, so I'm just guessing). But if energy spectrum is conserved, it seems very likely that momentum spectrum is also conserved, as they form a four-vector.

Comment: @kryomaxim: Nothing is an absolutely true fact. That does not change the fact that there is no way within *current* scientific knowledge to write down a consistent theory that does not obey Noether's theorem and/or has a non-conserved momentum, nor is there any experimental indication that we should look for such a theory.

Comment: @kristjan: This absolutely does not work in QFT, and "conservation of spectrum" is not really a thing. It is true that the probability to be in an energy eigenstate does not change over time (if the Hamiltonian is time-independent), but that is due to the fact that *the energy/Hamiltonian is the generator of time translation*. No other probability to be in eigenstates is conserved in this way, in general.

Comment: Ok, but if I solve particle interaction problems (classically), I still use stronger conditions than the conservation of momentum expectation value. For example, assuming only expectation value conservation for momentum, the reaction $e^+ + e^- -> \gamma$ should be allowed, as if the CM is in rest before the reaction, after the reaction the weighted sum of all possible outcomes for momentum is still zero. Previously I argued that the probabilities must also be conserved, but according to your comment, it seems this argument does not hold. Or has this something to do with these Ward identities?

Comment: @kristjan: Well, the waters get a bit muddy here, but you get away with using classical conservation laws for this because what comes out of the reaction is *not* a superposition of momentum states whose expectation value is zero. Sure, the (ensemble) average over many experiments is zero, but you do not get a superposition state, you get a definite momentum state as the asymptotic out state of the QFT interaction, or, at least, you can pretend you do. I'm not that sure about the details.

Answer (score 4):

From my readings;
the key to conservation of momentum appears to be based on defining a closed system to see if any mass crosses the boundaries of the system.

Answer (score 1):

If the quantum state has no defined momentum, as in the considered case, the standard law of conservation of momentum cannot applied evidently. What is conserved during the time evolution of the state, provided the Hamiltonian operator is translationally invariant (in particular it is the free Hamiltonian) is the probabilty of measuring a certain momentum, for every choice of that value of the momentum.

In particular, the expectation value is conserved together with all moments of the distribution of possible outcomes of the measurement of the momentum observable as well as the *quantum implementation* of the Noether theorem (regarding translational invariance).

In fact, *spatial homogeneity* aka *translational invariance*  of the quantum dynamics of a given quantum system means
$$V_x H V_x^\dagger = H \tag{0}\quad \mbox{for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$,}$$
where $V_x$ is the unitary implementation of translations and $H$ the Hamiltonian operator of the system. Eq.(0) implies (actually is equivalent to)
 $$V_x U_t = U_t V_x\tag{1}\quad \mbox{for all $x,t \in \mathbb{R}$}$$
where $U_t := e^{-itH}$ is the time evolutor of states.
 By definition the generator of $V_x$ is the momentum $P$ (along $x$) $$V_x = e^{-ixP}$$
(1) is equivalent to 
$$e^{-i xU_t^\dagger P U_t} = e^{-ixP}\mbox{for all $x,t \in \mathbb{R}$}$$
which, in turn, via Stone's theorem is equivalent to
$$U_t P U_t^\dagger = P\:.\tag{2}$$
Since $U_t$ is unitary (thus bounded) and decomposing according to its spectral decomposition $P = \int_{\mathbb{R}} p \:dQ^{(P)}(p)$, (2) implies 
$$U_t Q_E^{(P)}U_t^\dagger = Q_E^{(P)}\tag{3}$$
for every (Borel) set $E$ for instance of the form $(a,b)$. If $\psi_0$ is the normalized state vector at time $0$,
$$\langle \psi_0 |Q_E^{(P)} \psi_0 \rangle  = \|Q_E^{(P)} \psi_0\|^2$$
is the probability that the outcome $p$ of a momentum measurement at $t=0$ belongs to $E$. From (3) we finally have, defining $\psi_t := U_t \psi_0$ the state at time $t$,
$$\langle \psi_0 |Q_E^{(P)} \psi_0 \rangle =\langle \psi_t |Q_E^{(P)} \psi_t \rangle\:.\tag{4}$$
In other words: *the probability to find the value of $P$ in $E$ does not depend on time.*
It is possible to prove that this sort of invariance implies (0) and (1), so that (4) is the deepest physical meaning of *translational invariance* in quantum physics.

(4) implies that, for instance, the expectation value of $P$ is conserved along the time evolution, since (provided the integral in the right-hand side is defined)
$$\langle P\rangle_{\psi_t} = \int_{\mathbb R} p \: d\langle \psi_t |Q_E^{(P)} \psi_t \rangle = \langle P\rangle_{\psi_0}\:.$$
The same result is therefore  valid for every moment of the said probability distribution,
$$\langle P^n\rangle_{\psi_t} = \int_{\mathbb R} p^n \: d\langle \psi_t |Q_E^{(P)} \psi_t \rangle =\langle P^n\rangle_{\psi_0}\:,$$
so that, for instance, the standard deviation is also conserved in time.

Answer (score -1):

Conservation of momentum & energy don't hold true in a non-uniform gravitational field. Lets think 2 masses A & B free falls. Mass A is situated far away from mass B on earth such the non uniform nature of the gravitational field becomes significant. According to mass A, when mass B free falls under gravity, mass A thinks mass B is accelerating, instead of finding mass B at rest with respect to mass A. This means mass A thinks mass B is gaining momentum out of nowhere. Really the momentum that appears-to-be-gained is due to its motion in curved spacetime. Motion in curved line even if its with uniform velocity *has* acceleration as there is change in the direction of velocity. So when there is acceleration, velocity changes. When there is change in velocity, momentum changes. It is as if the spacetime is giving the mass B a gain in momentum. The same goes for energy. Mass A thinks mass B is gaining energy from nowhere or as if the spacetime is giving it (though again its the same aforementioned reason). (energy=momentum*velocity). So *its according to mass A* that there is violation of conservation laws of momentum & energy concerning the motion of mass B. This is basically due to inhomogeneity of spacetime in a non uniform gravitational field.

Also both conservation laws hold true only in closed systems. If you believe or assume a system is a closed one but find violation of conservation of momentum & energy, most probably there might be an external force or external source/sink of energy that you must have missed to identify.

Comment: Can I know if there is anything wrong with this answer?